# The 'rec_file' attribute has no file associated with it. django

Tags: python, django, image, request

I am working on a project where user is uploading a file and will be able to save the same
but i found the below mentioned error

**Html**

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
    {%for list in resource_list%}
    <td>{{list.resource_name}}</td>
                                                
    <td>
    <a href="{{list.rec_file.url}}" download><img style="max-width: 22px" src="{% static 'img/file.png' %}" ></a>
    </td>
```

**View.py**

```
def add_resources(request):
   

     title="Add Resources"
        requesturl = request.get_full_path
        title = 'Create Clinic'
        if request.method == "POST":
            resource_name = request.POST.get('resource_name')
            resource_file = request.FILES.get('resource_file')
            resource_instances = Resources.objects.create(
                resource_name = resource_name,
                rec_file = resource_file
            )
            resource_instances.save()
                
        return render(request, 'add_resources.html',{'title':title, 'requesturl':requesturl})
```

```
    def index(request):
        title="Resources List"
        requesturl = request.get_full_path()
        resource_list = Resources.objects.all()
        # FILES = Resources.objects.get(rec_file = request.rec_file)
        
        return render(request, 'resources_list.html', {
            'title':title, 
            'requesturl':requesturl, 
            'resource_list':resource_list,
            #  'resource_list1':FILES
            })
```

**error**

**The 'rec_file' attribute has no file associated with it.**

thanks